# How can I get the matched element's parent div attribute by regular express using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Have a html string see below.

```
<div sentence="11">
  <p>
    how are you Tom, how are you Tom
  </p>
</div>
<div sentence="12">
  <p>
    how are you Tom
  </p>
</div>
```

When user select the name 'Tom', I will replace the string 'Tom' using a name tag with some html style. The result what I want see below.

```
<div sentence="11">
  <p>
    how are you <span class="ano-subject" data-oristr="Tom" data-offset="1" data-sentence="11"><NAME></span>, how are you <span class="ano-subject" data-oristr="Tom" data-offset="2" data-sentence="11"><NAME></span>
  </p>
</div>
<div sentence="12">
  <p>
    how are you <span class="ano-subject" data-oristr="Tom" data-offset="1" data-sentence="12"><NAME></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

I will using the code below to do the replace.

```
var content = HTML CODE ABOVE;
var selectText = 'Tom';
var regex = new RegExp('(?=\\s|^|\\b)(?:' + selectText + ')(?=\\s|$|\\b)', "g");
var pre_sentence = 0;
var offset = 0；
content = content.replace(regex, function(match, position) {

    var curr_sentence = ???; // how can I get this element's parent div attribute 'sentence' ?

    if（pre_sentence != cur_sentence）{
        // this is new sentence.
        offset = 1;
        pre_sentence = curr_sentence;
    } else {
        offset++;
    }
    var replace = '<span class="ano-subject" data-oristr="Tom" data-offset="'+offset+'" data-sentence="'+curr_sentence+'"><NAME></span>';

    return replace;
});
```

Comment: Don’t mess around with HTML using regular expressions, use a proper DOM parser.

Comment: You can't easily get a reference to a parent element when you're still just working with a large string of HTML. This will be easier if you're modifying HTML that has already been added to the document (even invisibly) - you can loop through `<p>` elements discovered under the parent, and perform the given replacement, then use `p.parentNode` to refer to the div. This would be a lot of different code though